# TypeError: Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined when using router-link in vue

Tags: vue.js

I am using the following router link in a Vue component:

```html
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}"></router-link>
```

The rest of my app is as follows:

**Router.js**

```js
  new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'home',
      path: '/home',
      component: home,
    }
 ]})
```

**Main.js**

```js
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
  router,
}).$mount("#app");
```

Getting the below error when using router-link, but router.push() is working fine with routes.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_normalized' of undefined (vue.min.js:6)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Vue component use

```
<router-link to="/home"></router-link>
```